# Export Revit IFC works locally but fails in Design Automation (Revit 2023)

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to export a IFC file from a ~400Mb Revit file in Design Automation using the `Autodesk.Revit+2023` engine.

```cs
doc.Export(folder, filename, new IFCExportOptions());
```

Locally this works fine, but when running in Design Automation the export fails with:

> There has been an unrecoverable error during export.  This may be because the file is too large to export.  Try using filters and "Current View Only" mode, or look at the documentation for more suggestions.  Export will now be aborted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having the workitem ID, we are unable to debug this issue. However, we have had a report of a similar issue and a fix will be deployed later today. Please feel free to update if you still have this issue tomorrow.
In the meantime, you may use Autodesk.Revit+2024 where the issue is fixed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. I wasn't aware you could debug my issue based on the workitem id. Unfortunately I didn't save the id, but I will include ids in all future questions. I just started a new design automation run using Revit 2024 as you suggested and will update my response in about 2 hours. While the model is updating in DA I'm seeing a lot of these warnings `Failed to lock inter-process mutex IDSDKIpcServers-v2.lock in 10 secs.`. Could be irrelevant.

Comment: You're right, this may not be relevant for this specific issue at hand, but could be important for a separate issue. Please let me know the Workitem ID and if you're using an RCW model.

Comment: Using `Autodesk.Revit+2024` the IFC export worked. Thanks a lot. This also fixed another issue where DWG exports did ignore `MergedViews` setting. I tested another (smaller) model but it seems this time DA broke `ff1a120b46324cfdba1d0f8a56405017`. This workitem also has the aforementioned warning. I don't think this is a RCW model.

Comment: Hello - the fix has been deployed and 2023 should no longer have this problem. Please give it a shot when you can!

Comment: Hi. I can confirm everything works now using `Autodesk.Revit+2023`. Thanks!